# Convert NCPDP D.0 format to xml format in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, json

I'm trying to:

- Convert NCPDP D.0 format data to XML, then convert XML to JSON.
- Find the way to convert NCPDP D.0 to EDI and then convert EDI data to XML   and then XML to JSON.
- Find the way to convert NCPDP D.0 data to JSON direct.

Note: I want to make JSON format data, after the final conversion of NCPDP D.0 to JSON so I can show that data in any Frontend stack (React App).

I am finding the best possible way to convert the NCPDP D.0 data in to JSON

Comment: Ok, you've told us your goal. Do you have any issues implementing it? Remember that SO is here to help you to debug issues *with code you have written*. Because you've not shown any code here, there's nothing for us to help you with, so this question is likely to be closed.